ShadCN UI commands on terminal is not working
All of the sudden the commands for the shadcn ui library has stopped working.
I am getting the following on the terminal:
npx shadcn-ui@latest add button

sh: line 1: shadcn-ui: command not found


I tried:

resetting my connection
creating the project from scratch

but still doesn't work

god i hate web development. What is the point in making such a pointless name change if it breaks everyones code. ffs...

I found the solution, it turns out that ShadCN just updated their website and changed their CLI library name, which is why the old commands stopped working.
Here's the new way to do it according to their updated documentation:
Step 1: Initialize the Project
You now need to initialize your project using their new CLI tool. Run the following command:
npx shadcn@latest init

This will set up your project by installing the necessary dependencies, configuring Tailwind CSS, and adding CSS variables.
Step 2: Adding Components
To add components like button, use the updated command:
npx shadcn@latest add button

This will prompt you to select components or add them directly by specifying the component name.
Additional Tips:
If you're working within a monorepo, you can specify the working directory using the -c option:
npx shadcn@latest add button -c ./apps/www

It looks like ShadCN has made some improvements and changes, so make sure to check out their updated documentation for more details.

Why would they do that. Why would they change the CLI library name. Things actually working is so much more important than minor changes like that...

I think they simplified it. It is easy to type shadcn than shadcn-ui :)

Especially when every existing tutorial mentions shadcn-ui

I also don't like this change. It took me an hour to understand why can't I install the shadcn-ui madness!

Definitely should have added an error message to shadcn-ui pointing to the new CLI name.

There's an update to the installation process in the latest version. The shadcn-ui is no more in vogue, simply use shadcn.

Instead of: > npx shadcn-ui@latest add button
Do this: > npx shadcn@latest add button


The entire step in a new project could be like this:

npm install shadcn or npm install -g shadcn
npx shadcn@latest init
npx shadcn@latest add button


There's a bug in the latest version, try this...
npx shadcn-ui@0.8.0 add button


I use a WSL environment, and running npm i shadcn-ui worked for me (https://www.npmjs.com/package/shadcn-ui).
However, after installation, I encountered a high-severity issue related to lodash.template. I fixed it using npm audit fix --force.
Then I ran npx shadcn-ui init.
This solution is for those using WSL with Windows.

For installing latest shadcn-ui version 0.8.0 use this
npx shadcn-ui@0.8.0 init

It also work with pnpm.
